# SocketException: Connection failed (OS Error: Machine is not on the network, errno = 64), address = login.parker.com, port = 443 in android

Tags: flutter

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: SocketException: Connection failed (OS Error: Machine is not on the network, errno = 64), address = login.parker.com, port = 443
E/flutter ( 5780): #0      _NativeSocket.startConnect (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:682:35)
E/flutter ( 5780): #1      _RawSocket.startConnect (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1817:26)
E/flutter ( 5780): #2      RawSocket.startConnect (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:27:23)
E/flutter ( 5780): #3      RawSecureSocket.startConnect (dart:io/secure_socket.dart:299:22)
E/flutter ( 5780): #4      SecureSocket.startConnect (dart:io/secure_socket.dart:77:28)
E/flutter ( 5780): #5      _ConnectionTarget.connect (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2449:26)
E/flutter ( 5780): #6      _HttpClient._getConnection.connect (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2867:12)
E/flutter ( 5780): #7      _HttpClient._getConnection (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2872:12)
E/flutter ( 5780): #8      _HttpClient._openUrl (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2727:12)
E/flutter ( 5780): #9      _HttpClient.openUrl (dart:_http/http_impl.dart:2591:7)
E/flutter ( 5780): #10     IOClient.send (package:http/src/io_client.dart:35:38)
E/flutter ( 5780): #11     BaseClient._sendUnstreamed (package:http/src/base_client.dart:93:38)
E/flutter ( 5780): #12     BaseClient.post (package:http/src/base_client.dart:32:7)
E/flutter ( 5780): #13     post.<anonymous closure> (package:http/http.dart:69:16)
E/flutter ( 5780): #14     _withClient (package:http/http.dart:164:20)
E/flutter ( 5780): #15     post (package:http/http.dart:68:5)
```

Login failed using valid credentials.

Observation:
This only happens if App connected to the IOT device using Wi-FI. we retrieve information using ssh connection. after that, I click logout and login again we face this issue.
if I kill the app and open it again, then the login function works fine.

example of ssh connection:

```
client = SSHClient(
      host: '192.168.0.1',
      port: 22,
      username: _username,
      passwordOrKey: _password,
    );
```

why the login failed?